# pthread_join corrupts pthread_create argument in the stack

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I got this code from an advanced Linux programming book. When I try to execute the code under Linux 64bit environment the value of the `which_prime` variable gets corrupted (changes to 0) after `pthread_join()` function call.

In this example why the value of `which_prime` gets corrupted after running pthread_join?

In general can we use the 4th argument passed to pthread_create function safely inside main even if we call other functions like `pthread_join()`?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Compute successive prime numbers (very inefficiently). Return the
Nth prime number, where N is the value pointed to by *ARG. */
void* compute_prime (void* arg)
{
    int candidate = 2;

    int n = *((int*) arg);
    while (1) {
        int factor;
        int is_prime = 1;
        /* Test primality by successive division. */
        for (factor = 2; factor < candidate; ++factor)
            if (candidate % factor == 0) {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        /* Is this the prime number we’re looking for? */
        if (is_prime) {
            if (--n == 0)
                /* Return the desired prime number as the thread return value. */
                return (void*) candidate;
        }
        ++candidate;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int which_prime = 5000;
    int prime;
    /* Start the computing thread, up to the 5,000th prime number. */
    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime);
    /* Do some other work here... */
    /* Wait for the prime number thread to complete, and get the result. */
    pthread_join (thread, (void*) &prime);
    /* Print the largest prime it computed. */
    printf(“The %dth prime number is %d.\n”, which_prime, prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint: The prototype for `pthread_join` is `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);` -- look closely at that second parameter.

Answer (score 4):

We've arrived at a point in time where it is no longer safe to convert between an `int` and a `pointer`. That's because there are 64-bit systems where a pointer is 64-bits, but an `int` is only 32-bits.

So assuming 32-bit `int` and 64-bit pointer, here's what's happening in your code. The second argument to `pthread_join` is a pointer-to-a-pointer. In other words, you should be passing the address of a pointer (the address of a 64-bit value). Instead, you are passing the address of `prime` (the address of a 32-bit value). When `pthread_join` writes the result, it overwrites `which_prime`, because `which_prime` follows `prime` in memory.

To fix the problem, you need to avoid converting between `int`s and pointers. One way to do that is to avoid using the second parameter of `pthread_join`, as demonstrated by the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 20

typedef struct
{
    int success;
    int input;
    int output;
} stData;

void *doSomething( void *arg )
{
    stData *dataptr = arg;

    dataptr->success = 1;
    dataptr->output  = dataptr->input * 2;
    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    pthread_t id[NUM_THREADS];
    stData data[NUM_THREADS] = {{0}};

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        data[i].input = i + 1;
        pthread_create( &id[i], NULL, doSomething, &data[i] );
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        pthread_join( id[i], NULL );

        if ( data[i].success )
            printf( "thread %2d: input=%2d output=%2d\n", i+1, data[i].input, data[i].output );
        else
            printf( "thread %2d: failed\n", i+1 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or use an integer type specifically designed per the standard to be large enough to hold a data pointer: `intptr_t`.

Comment: @WhozCraig In general, I think it's best to avoid casting between pointer and integer types as much as possible. This is one of the cases where it is possible to avoid casting.

Comment: what happens if we have more than one child thread? How do we capture results from each thread? We can possibly use mutexes to protect the same data structure and let each thread update part of the data structure, but is there another (better) way?

Comment: @m-adolf -- I modified the sample code to show how to launch multiple threads, each with its own data. I did that by declaring an array of `data` structs in `main`, and then passing a different `data` struct to each thread.