# Sum of words using threads

Tags: c, multithreading

**Problem:** Implement a program that gets as arguments a file name followed by words. For each word, create a separate thread that counts its appearances in the given file.Print out the sum of the appearances of all words.

Below I did a code but I receive : Segmentaion Fault (core dumped) when I run it.

PS: I do not know if the code is correct and does the requirement succesfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx;

int sum = 0;
char filename[10];
char word[10];

void * voidCount(void* p){
    char cmd[100], appearences[100];
    FILE *f;
    sprintf(cmd, "echo %s | grep -o %s | wc -l", filename, word);
    f = popen(cmd, "r");
    fgets(appearences, sizeof(int), f);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    sum += *((int*)appearences);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    return NULL;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[argc-1];
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 1; i < argc-1; i++){
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
        strcpy(word, argv[i]);

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, voidCount, NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < argc-1; ++i){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("Total appearences: %d", sum);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So every thread is using the same `filename` and `word`?

Comment: Here's a syntax error preventing from compiling: `sum += *((int*)appearances;` -parentheses must match!

Comment: parentheses match now, but same error.

Comment: The way you're passing `filename` and `word` to the threads won't work. And filenames can easily be more than ten characters, even on old DOS systems with 8.3 filenames. And words can also be more than 10 characters. I've used at least one word in this comment that won't fit in a 10 byte buffer.

Comment: And you need to convert the string to an int (e.g. with atoi) - you can't just cast it like that. Pro tip: get a non-threaded version working correctly first - when you've fixed all the bugs in that then you can start adding threads.

Comment: See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573289/pthread-join-corrupts-pthread-create-argument-in-the-stack/28573518#28573518) which shows how to pass a structure to the thread functions.

Comment: having `word[]` as global variable does not make sense, because you will have as many words as entered as command line arguments. These strings have to be allocated and read from command line arguments into thread arguments, to be passed to each individual thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has to complete few tasks in order to solve the **problem**:

- set the number of threads depending on the number of words to search for
- properly allocate and initialize thread arguments
- pass each individual word as individual thread argument
- protect shared variables during computation
- get the results

Here's a minimal functional demo rework of your code with few essential comments. Word search is case sensitive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx;
int sum = 0;
char filename[10]; //declared global for simplicity
                   //we search all the words in the same file
void * voidCount(void* p){
    char  *word, cmd[100], appearences[100];
    int    num;
    FILE  *f;

    word =  ((char*)p);
    printf ("word : %s\n",word);    
    sprintf(cmd, "more %s | grep -o %s | wc -l", filename, word);//echo didn't work
    printf ("%s\n",cmd);    //debug print
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);    
    f = popen(cmd, "r");

    if(fgets(appearences, sizeof(appearences), f) == NULL)
        printf("Pipe error\n");     //better error handling is welcome...
    printf("Appearances of \"%s\": %s\n", word, appearences);

    num = atoi(appearances);    //convert string to int
    sum += num;    
    pclose(f);                  //close pipe
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[argc-1];    
    char **data = calloc(argc,sizeof(char*)); // initialize thread data
    int i = 0;
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);    
    for ( i = 2; i < argc; i++){
        data[i-2] = calloc(33, sizeof(char));//let's allow for somewhat longer words
        strcpy(data[i-2], argv[i]);
        strcat(data[i-2], "\0");
        pthread_create(&threads[i-2], NULL, voidCount, data[i-2]);//each word a thread arg
    }
    for (i = 0; i < argc-1; ++i){;
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("Total appearences: %d\n", sum);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)//free thread data
        free (data[i]);    
    free (data);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this can help.